# Convert Localizable.strings to json

Tags: ios, localization

I want to convert  Localizable.strings file to JSON:

```
"Key" = "Localized Str";
```

To

```
"Key" : "Localized Str",
```

Is there any ready solution? Or better write own script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable"
                                                 ofType:@"strings"
                                            inDirectory:nil
                                        forLocalization:@"en"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: anyway to do this in kotlin or java

Comment: and how to convert a dict to a Localizable.strings file?